# Simple URLDecoder issue

Tags: android, webview, urldecode

I'm having trouble decoding simple url. This is an example from my issue:

```
String sb = "<body>" + "<script>" + "document.body.innerHTML += '<a href=\"http://www.azerty.com/?s=4&a=50 %\" style=\"display: none;\" id=\"link\">Link</a>';" +"document.getElementById(\"link\").click();" +"</script>" +"<body>";

mContentWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mContentWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mContentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(URI,sb, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

When shouldOverrideUrlLoading invoked it give me http://www.azerty.com/?s=4&a=50%20% and when I try to read the value of with URLDecoder.decode(response_value, "UTF-8") "a" my app crash with this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence at 5: 50%20%

I do not understand why the % was not encoded by my webview to %25.
sb is dynamic string comes from my server.

Can any one one give me hint how I can solve this and be able to read "a" and "b.

Thx.

Comment: Would you mind to remove the horizontal scrollbar? It would improve the readability.

Comment: focus on the expression ending "a=50"spacepercent.  it is not the end of a valid URI.   if u start with a valid object and then it gets encoded, the output of the encoding will be valid. if u continue having problems , u might try encoding only the values of the KV pairs within the query portion of the URI

Comment: I I didn't quite understood the first part can u give an example.But i tried already the second part with 
decodeValue(url,"a");
private String decodeValue(String var, String neededKey) {

        Uri url = Uri.parse(var);
        Set<String> paramNames = url.getQueryParameterNames();
        for (String key: paramNames) {
            if(neededKey.equals(key)) return url.getQueryParameter(key);
        }
        return "";
    }
but it gives 50 �

Comment: after the "a=50"
the next 2 bytes ...
space
%

are what u need to look at .. not a valid end to the KV portion of the query portion of the URI.

Comment: I used workaround based on java Class URLDecoder doc

"A sequence of the form "%xy" will be treated as representing a byte where xy is the two-digit hexadecimal representation of the 8 bits. Then, all substrings that contain one or more of these byte sequence..." from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

if Class URLDecoder throw a IllegalArgumentException i replace every % with %25 when the next 2char of the %  are not hex value.This approach solved my issue
@ Robert Rowntree thx for ur time :)